# How to open data folder from android

Tags: applications

http://postfiles6.naver.net/20130808_261/fermat22_1375962717749SdDOq_PNG/info.png?type=w3

This is app info
(setting->application manager->app)

I want reading this app's data(261mb) but i can't finding this folder.

How to find(or open) this app's data folder

Comment: If your device is not rooted, you cannot access any app's data folder.

Comment: The link you posted is dead: it gives a "Referral denied" error. I strongly recommend using the built-in "Upload image" feature to add your screenshot (if you must add one at all) instead of using some dodgy third-party site.

Comment: @DanHulme I guess he lacks the necessary rep for that.

Answer (score 2):

An app whose package name is `com.example.app` has its data files in `/data/data/com.example.app`. This applies to pre–Jelly Bean systems, and to the first user on Jelly Bean systems. For other users on Jelly Bean systems, user 1 has the data files for `com.example.app` in `/data/user/1/com.example.app`, and so on.

Reading another app's data files can only be done on a *rooted* phone. Even then, you need an app that's designed to work with root access. See the [rooting](/questions/tagged/rooting) tag wiki, and [How do I root my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device) for more info, but bear in mind that rooting will **void your warranty**.